# some font awesome show and some showing something wrong

Tags: html, fonts, font-awesome

`<i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye" style="color:#007bff;"></i>`

[image]

Please tell me the exact reason why this happen some font are showing while other show something else

Comment: It is not Laravel related question. Check your `cdn`s and make sure you are using right version

Comment: Which version of FontAwesome are you using?

Comment: Check the version of cdn you are using.  Since, the class depends on the version, it is displaying classes which are compatible for that version .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML it's hard to say why.

But, here is Font Awesome 6.12 working fine with `fa-eye`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <span class="fa fa-lg fa-pencil"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-lg fa-box-archive"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"></span>
</div>
```